# Techniques for finding functions with known values and derivatives at two points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, plane-curves

I want to find a function $\gamma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ such that for two values of $t$, we have $\gamma'(t)$ and $\gamma(t)$ have some value, and at no point does the curvature ever exceed $r$.

What sort of techniques can I use to find such a function?

I know how to this for one value of $t$ (it would just be a line with the desired slope and intercept), but I don't know how to combine the results for both values of $t$.

How can I approach this problem?

**EDIT:** If it helps, the known values of $\gamma$ (and $\gamma'$) are real numbers, not dependent on any variables.

Comment: One possibility is using differential equation of a conic( total 5 points or conditions including one for curvature)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean more?

Comment: Derive a fifth order ODE and solve as BVP for a standard conic by successive differentiation.

Comment: @Narasimham Would you mind writing this as an answer? I really don't have the background to understand what you mean in a comment

Comment: $a x^2 + 2 h xy + b y^2 + c x + d y + 1 = 0$ , please start differentiation with respect to arc $s, \, ( \cos \phi= dx/ds, \sin \phi= dy/ds ) $

Comment: Do you mean parameterize that equation in terms of arc length?